# How to return the full view of the data while using rest api

Tags: json, linux, api, rest

There is POST [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/253550/python3-conditionally-moving-files-and-string-formatting) which is calling a rest API to fetch the data.

Below is Just the Short code using rest API Call  to fetch the data using /rest/resource-alerts, but it only displays max 500 Critical alerts not all.  Below is the Code I'm using:

```
sessionID=$(curl -k -H "accept: application/json" -H "content-type: application/json" -H "x-api-version: 120" -d '{"userName":"administrator","password":"123456"}' -X POST https://synergy.ksg.com/rest/login-sessions | jq -r ".sessionID")
# cUrl command with header and payload information to ftech the Data using API call
CMD=$(curl -k -H 'accept: application/json' \
        -H 'content-type: text/csv' \
        -H 'x-api-version: 2' \
        -H "auth: $sessionID" \
        -X 

GET https://synergy.ksg.com/rest/resource-alerts)
echo "$CMD"
```

However, while today going via API DOC I see the `Query Parameters` , The section says about the count, does anyone know how to get the full list of messages?

Below is the

[image]